# i get a 404 error in a EJB3 project that worked pefectly

Tags: java, servlets, ejb-3.0, glassfish-3

i'm trying to see an old EJB3 project that i did at school but the only thing i can see is the index.jsp on the browser. The error i get is:

`SEVERE: Class [ Lse/ernesto/databaseStuff/DbManagerLocal; ] not found. Error while loading [ class se.ernesto.client.UpdateEventServlet ]`

The **DBManagerLocal** is an interface for a stateless session bean. The **UpdateEventServlet** is a servlet in the Dynamic Web Project. Note that i have added the EJB Project to the WEB Project's build path.

The other jsp files are in the WEB-INF folder in my Dynamic Web Project. But it seems it doesn't find the servlets which are responsible for loading these jsp files. This is weird because the project was working before (1 year ago) Since then i updated to OSX Lion, i don't know if there's an issue with the new OS and EJB3. 
The project is composed by a Dynamic Web Project, a EJB3 Project and an EAR Project, all of those are deployed via Eclipse in a Glassfish server. Has anyone run into this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that the web container cannot find the class / interface because it is "not there".  Or more precisely, because it is not in the place or places that it is expecting to find it.

What I would do is to do a thorough search of the directory tree *of the web container*.  Start with the installed webapp's WEB-INF/classes directory, including any JAR files in that directory.  Then look in the shared library area.

If *you* can't find the class, or a JAR containing the class, then that's your problem.  If you can find it but the web container code can't, it is probably in the wrong place.  Either way, something is broken in your (current) build / deploy processes; e.g. your project's Eclipse settings.

(Why did it work before?  Who knows.  Perhaps you are building / deploying differently.  Perhaps you deployed something manually ... )

Comment: Well i went (in Finder) to: glassfish/domains/myDomain/eclipseApps/myProject/and found the class there **DBManagerLocal.class** The jsp files and JAR files are also there. I don't know if i have to go to the admin **localhost:4848** to fix it. I don't remember doing anything in the admin to make this run. The EJB Project has no JAR files as it should be and the MANIFEST.MF looks like this: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path:` should there be a class name in **Class-Path:**?

Comment: @madcoderz - in short, I don't know.  But clearly, something must be wrong or else Glassfish would have found that class.

Comment: i'll keep looking for the solution today. Thanks for your time.